# regex: In Python, how do I match one of many words if the words can contain each other

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex expression such that I can match this pattern

`INTEGER YR INTEGER MTH`

where INTEGER is `\d+` and YR is one of "y", "yr", "yrs", "year" and MTH is one of "m", "mth", "mths", "month", "months".

So I tried to match the year first so I write this

```
YEAR_STRING = "[(y)|(yr)|(yrs)|(year)|(years)]"

m = re.search(f'\d+ {YEAR_STRING}', '10 year 2 months')
```

However, `m.group(0)` returns '10 y' instead of '10 year'. I want it to match full words. What's the error in my regex?

Also, I want to this to fail e.g. '10 yeard 2 mth' this shouldn't match anything as `yeard` is not in my list of words.

Comment: `[(y)|(yr)|(yrs)|(year)|(years)]` is a character class that matches `(`, or `y`, or `)`, or `|` and so on. So, only *one* of the characters listed inside the square brackets.

Comment: Oh, so get rid of square braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a character class, not an alternation, which you should be using:

```
year_regex = r'\b(?:years|year|yrs|yr|y)\b'
m = re.findall(r'\d+\s+' + year_regex, '10 year 2 months')
print(m)
```

This prints:

```
['10 year']
```

Your character class was actually searching for a set of the individual characters contained inside, but you want to search for words.  Also, equally important, Python's regex engine will scan the above alternation from left to right.  We places longer terms, e.g. `years`, first, before `year`, so that we will try to match the former first, and only consider the latter in the event that the former cannot be found.